# What is the verb tense of "is/are met"?

Tags: verb-forms

What is the verb tense of "is/are met?"
I encountered "is/are met" most of the time. 
Could you please explain this?
Is this in present tense?

Comment: Please provide a sentence to serve as a specific example.

Comment: *Is* and *are* are present tense forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are present tense.  The construction is used when the number (singular versus plural) of the subject of the verb is unknown or can vary:  one condition **is** met, or two conditions **are** met.

Because what is being said can apply to situations where there is one or more, and the number of the verb would be different depending on the answer, writers of legal documents, forms, etc. provide both forms of the verb so the sentence can be read grammatically.

Answer (score 0):

Redpenner is right, but just to muddy up the waters a bit...

You could say **is met** is a reflection on the hoped-for present, that has yet to occur, in at least this scenario.  Example:

> The deal is met when our conditions are met.

The "is met" talks about the singular *deal* and implies "will be met" because of the *when*, and "will be" is a future tense of *to be*.  You could even legally replace "is met" with "will be met", here.  "Are met" refers to the plural *conditions*.

So even though it is saying something using the present verb *is*, it is referring to the situation you will find yourself in, in the future, because of "when", and could be treated as such.